# How can I reuse the same impl destructor in a class derived from a PIMPL base class?

Tags: c++, inheritance, unique-ptr, pimpl-idiom

I'm trying to create a class that inherits from a base class that uses the PIMPL idiom.

I have a base class `base.h`:

```
#include <memory>

class Base {
 public:
  class Impl;
  Base(std::unique_ptr<Base::Impl> impl);
  virtual ~Base();

 private:
  std::unique_ptr<Base::Impl> impl_;
};
```

which is implemented in `base.cpp`:

```
#include "base.h"

class Base::Impl {
 public:
  Impl() {}
  ~Impl() {}
};

Base::Base(std::unique_ptr<Base::Impl> impl) : impl_(std::move(impl)) {}
Base::~Base() {}
```

which is then derived in `derived.cpp`:

```
#include "base.h"

class Derived : public Base {
 public:
  Derived() : Base(nullptr) {}
  ~Derived() override {}
};
```

When I compile these three files, I get the following error:

```
In file included from /usr/include/c++/7/memory:80:0,
                 from base.h:1,
                 from derived.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/unique_ptr.h: In instantiation of ‘void std::default_delete<_Tp>::operator()(_Tp*) const [with _Tp = Base::Impl]’:
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/unique_ptr.h:268:17:   required from ‘std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>::~unique_ptr() [with _Tp = Base::Impl; _Dp = std::default_delete<Base::Impl>]’
derived.cpp:5:27:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/unique_ptr.h:76:22: error: invalid application of ‘sizeof’ to incomplete type ‘Base::Impl’
  static_assert(sizeof(_Tp)>0,
```

which kind of makes sense, since there is no `~Impl()` for the derived class to use. After I add the following snippet to `derived.cpp` before the `Derived` class definition:

```
class Base::Impl {
 public:
  Impl() {}
  ~Impl() {}
};
```

it compiles fine. Is there any way for `derived.cpp` to use the `Impl` destructor from `base.cpp` without adding it to some other shared file that both `base.cpp` and `derived.cpp` use? I've also noticed that this issue only arises because of the constructor taking in a `unique_ptr` to `Base::Impl`. If I replace that constructor with an empty constructor that just assigns a `new Impl` to `Base::impl_`, I don't have to include the destructor like I had to above. What's different in that situation?

Comment: The problem is the conversion of `nullptr` into a `std::unique_ptr<Base::Impl>` happening outside of Base.cpp where `Impl` is fully defined. This leads to the reason why I'm not trying to answer this: I can't provide a good solution. If only `Base` knows how to make a `Impl`, how will `Derived` ever get an `Impl` to supply to `Base`? This constructor seems minimally useful. Or maybe I do have a solution.... Lemme think.

Comment: It does seem a bit strange, but for context, the `Derived` class in my use case is a mock, so I have no need to construct an `Impl`.

Comment: Advice would be don't then. Add another constructor to `Base`. `Base::Base() : impl_(nullptr) {}` That said, I hate *hate **hate*** modifying a class to support a test. It means you are not testing the proper use-cases of the system under test and the test results may be questionable.

Comment: Thinking didn't coalesces into a decent solution, by the way.